# WatchKit Extension Bundle ID Unavailable

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I've added a watch kit app to my iOS app and everything was working fine and running well until I wanted to share data between the two apps.

Whenever I try to add the 'App Groups' capability on the watch kit extension, it tells me that my bundle ID (com.myrealappid.watchkitextension) is not available.

[image: WatchKit Extension Bundle ID Unavailable]
It also informs me that 'No matching provisioning profiles found' in the General tab, and if I try to fix it, it also says that the App ID (com.myrealappid.watchkitextension) is not available.

[image: App ID Unavailable]
Logging into the members centre I can't find any reference to a bundle ID with the suffix 'watchkitextension'. I also can't re-add this bundle ID within the members centre because it seems to think it already exists as well.

Has anyone come across this before or have any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: See my answer to another related question, that should clarify it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found/29272260#29272260

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that another developer account that I use in Xcode had the missing ID. The apps are completely unrelated and belong to different clients of mine so I've no idea how it ended up there.

I deleted the Bundle ID from that account and everything is working as expected now.

If this happens anyone else, check any other developer accounts you have access to. That might just be where the missing Bundle ID is.

Comment: Been banging my head on this one all day. Big thanks.

Comment: I believe the reason to "how it ended up there" is "App IDs must be globally unique (not just unique within your iTunes account)".

Comment: @AndyDunn I am not seeing that bundle ID in the account.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like someone already used that specific Bundle Identifier if you can't find it in your member center.

You need to create another Bundle ID in this case.

Comment: The problem is the main part of the Bundle ID is already in use by our main iOS app. Adding ".watchkitextension" to the end shouldn't be a problem, because no-one else should have that ID in use.

Comment: I had similar issue and in my case I had 2 Apple accounts linked to Xcode and Xcode automatically created a bundle id for the extension extension in the wrong account which made the id 'taken'.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @KostyaKim. I'll have to check into that as I have a bunch of Apple accounts setup in Xcode.