# WatchKit Upload

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to submit my WatchKit app t iTunesConnect. I click "Archive" and then validate and I am shown the message below. I have created an App Id for the app, extension and WatchKit App as well as distribution profiles.
Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

[image: Error]

Comment: I had similar inital issues, I would guess you have wrong bundle identifiers for your Watchkit stuff. Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found/29272260#29272260

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To properly sign a watch app, you need three different App IDs and each App ID needs a provision profile.

1. Go to [Developer Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter)
2. Add/Edit the three App IDs:

   - One for your main App bundle, you may need to add the entitlements you need, like `App Groups`, `Keychain Access Group`.
   - One for your watchkit extension bundle, you may need to add the entitlements you need.
   - One for your watchkit app bundle. No entitlements needed.
3. Delete the distribution provision profiles for the three App IDs, if they already exists.
4. Add three new distribution provision profiles for the three App IDs.
5. Now go back to Xcode, open `Preference` and go to `Accounts`.
6. Choose your Apple ID, click `View Details` on the bottom right.
7. Click the `refresh` button on the bottom left, wait for the list of provision profiles to change.
8. In `Build Settings` for all your targets, configure the `Code Signing` part as below.

[image: Code Signing]

9. Try Archive again.
10. When you submit your app, XCode will ask you to confirm the provision profile it uses to sign each of your bundles. You need to be sure that the provision profile names match those you configured in Developer Member Center.

Comment: You should not use "Automatic" for Provisioning Profile of the Extension, it's likely to not work. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found/29272260#29272260

Comment: @dogsgod If you only have one provisioning profile for one APP ID in one type, XCode will find the right one to sign.

Comment: maybe Xcode 6.3 can do that, Xcode 6.2 can't, went through that when I uploaded ...

Answer (score 2):

I have uploaded one app to itunesconnect with watch app.

This is very simple. You need to create 3 appstore provisioning profiles and the bundle identifier for the extention and watchApp are like

```
com.abc.app      - Phone app
com.abc.app.extention - Extention
com.abc.app.watchapp  - watch app
```

and also sync app group in capabilities tab in all 3 targets.

All are well.

you just needs to create Archive for only Phone App (Main Target). That's It. When user will download your app. And if phone have attached Watch then this will automatically get informed to you for watchapp download.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the screenshot, it looks like your profiles need to have the missing entitlements (beta-reports-active, keychain-access-groups) added to them.

Comment: Where do I need to add these?

Comment: Select your target in Xcode and check out the "Capabilities" tab.

Comment: The error seems to be for the WatchKit App which doesn't have that tab. The extension does but seems to be fine.

Comment: It specifically mentions the extension in the error message. I'd double-check the profiles in the Developer Center and make sure everything looks okay and that those profiles are set to be used for the Release scheme in your build settings.

Comment: I assumed that the extensions and WatchKit a App needed different provisioning profiles? Is this true or should they be set to the same?

Comment: No, you're correct. Different app ids, different profiles, etc.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll check everything again and let you know.

Comment: I have deleted them and recreated them but I am still seeing the same message. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a provisioning profile for the watchkit extension as well as the provision that you have for your app.

If you download the Apple Lister App Code Sample there is a guide to getting started that show you everything that you need to do to setup your app to work properly on a device with Apple Watch.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html

Click on the `Download Sample Code` button, and in that folder there is a file called `iOS and Watch Quick Start.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Using XCode 6.3 solved the problem to me. 
I previously used 3 provisionning profiles for watch apps
source : [Watchkit Extension - No matching provisioning profiles found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found)