# WatchKit Invalid Binary

Tags: xcode, binary, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have uploaded an app update with my WatchKit extension but it keeps saying "Invalid Binary" in iTunes Connect. Do I need to tell iTunes Connect that it should include a WatchKit app anywhere?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found/29272260#29272260

Answer (score 3):

I checked the email from iTunesConnect and the issue was that my app icons had an alpha channel. I corrected the icons and now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Folks submitting zipped app files will run into this validation error as well because zipped apps are no longer supported for apps containing a watch extension. Follow these steps to generate a submittable .ipa file instead:

**Supporting Raw Zip Watch App Submissions**
App Store import validation ensures that watch app submissions include additional files alongside the submitted bundle that are generated by Xcode. This prevents you from using the old submission workflow of submitting a zipped app file using Application Loader.

However, if you have a build process which currently prevents submitting the watch app using Xcode, you may use the following process to generate the necessary .ipa file to be submitted using Application Loader:

1. Create a directory named WatchKitSupport as a sibling to Payload
2. Copy a binary named "WK" from the iOS 8.2 SDK in Xcode to your new WatchKitSupport directory. This binary can be found at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/Library/Application Support/WatchKit/
3. Do not touch or re-sign the WK binary in any way
4. Compress everything into a zip and rename the file extension to .ipa

**Note**: You may compare your .ipa with one generated by Xcode by exporting an .ipa from an archive of a new Xcode project template for which you have added a watch target.

The format of the resulting IPA should contain (at least):

`myApp.ipa
|________Payload/
|________Symbols/
|________WatchKitSupport/
                        |_____WK`

Comment: Im getting "invalid binary" as well with no email as to why and I checked my IPA and its exactly as you describe with the WatchKitSupport folder containing the WK binary.

Comment: Ah, the old "no email" for invalid binary status. Okay, I've seen cases where an exception occurs while the server processes the email template (thus bailing on the email sending). In this case, you've gotta go to iTunesConnect.apple.com support (submit a help ticket via Contact Us link at the bottom after signing in). They'll hand deliver you the reason. Be sure to use the "iTunes Connect Upload or General Help" topic!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same thing when I submitted my WatchKit app this morning.  I also got an email from Apple saying why it was invalid.  I was using a third party class called Reachability that is the same name as a private API.  I removed Reachability and checked for readability another way and I was able to submit.