# Run iOS App with WatchKit Extension on iOS 7 device in Xcode6.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, xcode-6.2

My iOS app has a deployment target of 7.0 and my WatchKit App of 8.2.

Xcode won't allow me to run the iOS app on an iOS 7 device. It says my WatchKit App has a deployment target of 8.2 so it can't run on an iOS 7 device. If I change the deployment target of the WatchKit App then the project fails to build.

How can I run an app from Xcode with a WatchKit App on iOS 7?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 has no support for the Apple Watch.
Setting your deployment target to iOS 7 does allow to install the main app on that platform but that app does still only support the Watch on iOS 8 devices.

Chose an iOS 8.x simulator, and it should work.
You also need to have the right set of Provisioning Profiles for debug (and release) configured - at least for me automatic stopped to work on Xcode 6.3.

Comment: I understand iOS 7 doesn't support the Apple Watch. I just need to test the main app on iOS 7.

Comment: Could you maybe post more details around your error and target s and schemes? Testing the main app on a 7.x simulator works absolutely fine for me - certainly no Watch simulator!

Comment: Works on iOS 7 simulator. This is only a device issue.

Comment: Then you have most probably issues with your Provisioning Profiles, see some details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found/29272260#29272260

Comment: I've already submitted to the App Store, so it's not a provisioning issue. I'm trying to debug on an iOS 7 device, but I can't select the device. With Xcode server I was able to put the app on the device over the air. I found a minor bug and I'm trying to debug on the device from Xcode.

Comment: Still sounds like PP issue. Do you have a second set of PPs for debug configured and assigned? With Xcode 6.3 you can not use 'automatic' setting and wildcard PPs for debug. I had a similar issue, I also have my app submitted but could not do a debug build anymore after update to 6.3 (although it did validate fine)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to launch the "PhotoMind WatchKit App" target.  Is this the watchkit app?  Try switching the target to the iPhone app.

Comment: No. It is the PhotoMind iOS target.