# xCode - "Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution" when trying to submit app

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit my app to Apple via xCode.  I am getting an error message "Your Account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate. If you have your signing identity on another Mac, you can import a developer profile.  You can also revoke the current certificate and request one again."  I see there are several posts related to this on StackOverflow.  I have tried all of them - revoking and requesting another cert, updating xCode, etc.  I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Go to apple developer website, download your developer profile. Did you change your Mac?

Comment: It would be helpful if you linked to the exact SO questions you've already looked at so people don't suggest something you've already tried in your 'etc'.

Comment: Where do you download your developer profile from the developer site?  And then how do you install it it Xcode?

Comment: Yes.  I did change my Mac.  My previous one crashed.  I'm not able to get to it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it might not seem related at first sight, I think [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29272260/4206060). 
Ignore the Watch part ...

tl,dr: get your provisioning profiles set up as required.

Comment: Sorry, no. I had the same issue and I resolved it with switching from automatic to explicit PP and then the force refresh ... Maybe that was also related to having 2 accounts with similar setup, but that's just a guess.