# none of valid provisioning profile allowed the specified entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode6.3.1

I am creating ipa of my App in `xCode 6.3.1.`

After archive when I click on export-->> Save for adHoc deployment and getting following error:

> none of valid provisioning profile allowed the specified
>   entitlements:com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api.

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Delete all the certificates from keychain, Then create new development profile and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting all the certificates from **Keychain**, Then create new development profile and add it.

This works most of the time..

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the following reference,you get some idea.

[Watchkit Extension - No matching provisioning profiles found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found/29272260#29272260[1])