# Xcode 6 error: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

So I have been stuck on this for about 2 weeks now. I have combed through so many SO answers, Apple Developer Forums, and have even been on the phone with Apple Technical Support for many hours on multiple occasions. Even after all of these things, I have yet to get an answer. Since not even Apple knows what to do about it, I am relying on you!

I am trying to submit an update to my app, with a watch kit extension, but it is no longer working. About 3 weeks ago, I submitted an update for this app successfully. Now when I try, when Xcode validates, it gives me the error: "None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: beta-reports-active, com.apple.security.application-groups, application-identifier"

I have read and tried many answers, such as this one: [Watchkit Extension - No matching provisioning profiles found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found/29272260#29272260)

but still no luck.

What I've most recently done is reset Xcode to do automated provisioning (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1814/_index.html) but that didn't work either.

Someone please end my grief!

Comment: Provisioning profiles are only valid for one year. Is your provisioning profile over one year old? Did making Xcode auto provision generate a new profile?

Comment: I created all new provisioning profiles earlier today while trying to follow the instructions in the first link i provided