# No matching profisioning profiles found error ios xcode 6.3.2

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

Can someone help..I am getting the following error while creating an ipa file.I tried so many questions and solutions in stackoverflow.But no use.my xcode is 6.3.2

[image]

Comment: Please give more details about your Xcode version...etc Are you using beta version of Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Check these steps to find the issue,

1. Check the provisioning profile used in the Project and target are valid and correct one under build settings.
2. Check team under Target - General - Team(valid account)
3. Clean the project (Product ->Clean) and build again.
4. Check provisioning profile type (dev or adhoc)

for more details refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/import_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH9-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Re-create your entitlement file, seems it's different than your provision profile's team. If you have Watchkit app and Watchkit Extension you need to go developer portal and then correct bundle identifier for your Watchkit app and Watchkit Extension.

Also check my answer and try :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30618721/4145420

Let me know if it's fix @iosDeveloper_Junior

Comment: I dont have any watchkit in my app.

Comment: HOw to Re-create the entitlement file,?